# Why sometimes do I have to call compute() twice on dask delayed functions?

Tags: class, dask, dask-delayed

I'm working with dask delayed functions and I'm getting familiar with the do's and don'ts when using the `@dask.delayed` decorator on functions. I realized that sometimes I will need to call `compute()` twice to get the result despite the fact that I thought I followed the best practices. i.e. don't call a dask delayed function within another dask delayed function.

I've run into this problem in two scenarios: when there are nested functions, and when calling a member function in a class that uses class members that are delayed objects.

```py
@dask.delayed
def add(a, b):
    return  a + b

def inc(a):
    return add(a, 1)

@dask.delayed
def foo(x):
    return inc(x)

x = foo(3)
x.compute()
```

```
class Add():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @dask.delayed
    def calc(self):
        return self.a+self.b

a = dask.delayed(1)
b = dask.delayed(2)
add = Add(a, b)
add.calc().compute()
```

In the first example, `x.compute()` does not return the result but another delayed object, and I will have to call `x.compute().compute()` to get the actual result. But I believe inc is not a delayed function and therefore it's not against the rule of not calling a delayed function within another delayed function?

In the second example, again I will have to call `add.calc().compute().compute()` to get the actual result. In this case `self.a` and `self.b` are just delayed attributes and there are no nested delayed function anywhere.

Can anyone help me understand why I need to call `compute()` twice in these two cases? Or even better, could someone briefly explain the general 'rule' when using dask delayed functions? I read the documentation and there's not so much to be found there.

Update:
@malbert pointed out that the examples require calling `compute()` twice because there is delayed results involved in a delayed function and therefore it counts as 'calling delayed function within another delayed function'. But why something like follows only requires calling `compute()` once?

```py
@dask.delayed
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

a = dask.delayed(1)
b = dask.delayed(2)
c = add(a,b)
c.compute()
```

In this example, `a` and `b` are also both delayed results, and they are used in a delayed function. My random guess would be what actually matters is where the delayed result is in a delayed function? It's probably only fine if they are passed in as arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key lies in understanding more precisely what `dask.delayed` does.

Consider

```
my_delayed_function = dask.delayed(my_function)
```

When used as a decorator on `my_function`, `dask.delayed` returns a function `my_delayed_function` which delays the execution of `my_function`. When `my_delayed_function` is called with an argument

```
delayed_result = my_delayed_function(arg)
```

this returns an object which contains all the necessary information about the execution of `my_function` with the argument `arg`.

Calling

```
result = delayed_result.compute()
```

triggers the execution of the function.

Now, the effect of using operators such as `+` on two delayed results is that a new delayed result is returned which bundles the two executions contained in its inputs. Calling `compute` on this object triggers this bundle of executions.

---

So far so good. Now, in your first example, `foo` calls `inc`, which calls a delayed function, which returns a delayed result. Therefore, computing `foo` does exactly this and returns this delayed result. Calling `compute` on this delayed result (your "second" compute) then triggers its computation.

In your second example, `a` and `b` are delayed results. Adding two delayed results using `+` returns the delayed result of bundling the execution of `a`,`b` and their addition. Now, since `calc` is a delayed function, it returns a delayed result on getting a delayed result. Therefore again, its computation will return a delayed object.

In both cases, you didn't quite follow the [best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed-best-practices.html). Specifically the point

> Avoid calling delayed within delayed functions

since in your first example the delayed `add` is called within `inc`, which is called in `foo`. Therefore you are calling delayed within the delayed `foo`. In your second example, the delayed `calc` is working on the delayed `a` and `b`, therefore again you are calling delayed within a delayed function.

In your question, you say

> But I believe inc is not a delayed function and therefore it's not
>   against the rule of not calling a delayed function within another
>   delayed function?

I suspect you might be understanding "calling delayed within delayed functions" wrongly. This refers to everything that happens within the function and is therefore part of it: `inc` includes a call of the delayed `add`, therefore delayed is being called in `foo`.

*Addition after question update*: Passing delayed arguments to a delayed function bundles the delayed executions into the new delayed result. This is different from "calling delayed within the delayed function" and is part of the intended use case. Actually I also didn't find a clear explanation of this in the documentation, but one entry point might be [this](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/3eb2dc89c9a70dcb828e86d043e23b751ab0d0fd/dask/delayed.py#L46): `unpack_collections` is used to process delayed arguments. Even if this should remain somewhat unclear, sticking to the best practices (interpreted this way) should produce a reproducible behaviour regarding the output of `compute()`.

The following codes result when sticking to "Avoid calling delayed within delayed functions" and return a result after a single call of `compute`:

First example:

```py
#@dask.delayed
def add(a, b):
    return  a + b

def inc(a):
    return add(a, 1)

@dask.delayed
def foo(x):
    return inc(x)

x = foo(3)
x.compute()
```

Second example:

```py
class Add():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    #@dask.delayed
    def calc(self):
        return self.a+self.b

a = dask.delayed(1)
b = dask.delayed(2)
add = Add(a, b)
add.calc().compute()
```

Comment: Great appreciation for your explanation. However there's still something that I can't quite absorb. Please see my updated question. Thanks!

Comment: That's a great example you added. Check my answer edit